# How do you know if Tomcat Server is installed on your PC

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, jasperserver

I am using Windows 7 OS.
   I just installed jaspersoft server which installed Apache Tomcat and mysql as a bundle along with it.

I go to  `http://localhost:8080` and theres a message that says webpage is not available.

I am a beginner, and I would like to know if Tomcat is first installed on my computer. Can you tell 
me how I can do that ? ( I would also like to know if it has to be started and on what
port it was installed.)

**UPDATE**

Heres something I did . i am really confused now . I found the location of the tomcat server. I found the server.xml file. The port in the server.xml file was listed as 8005. I also found start.bat which I ran. I now see that `http://localhost:8080` works but `http://localhost:8005` doesnt .  Would you know why ?? The port 8005 should work because thats what was listed in the server.xml

Comment: Just because Tomcat is installed doesn't mean it's running.

Comment: Go to desktop, press F3 key and in the Search input text write *tomcat*. It will take some time but will give you the directory where it is installed.

Comment: check if you have `java` process running in your task manager, if there no one, your tomcat is not running, note this rule doesn't work backwards, and add `/manager` context path to your url like this `http://localhost:8080/manager`,

Comment: @EugenHalca a java process can run for other process that uses the JVM like Eclipse or Netbeans (apart from the eclipe.exe and netbeans.exe processes). Also, OP already stated that accessing `http://localhost:8080` gives nothing, which means: 1) Tomcat has not started. 2) Tomcat tried to start but failed since other application uses port 8080. 3) Tomcat installation shipped with jasper server points to another port.

Comment: Heres something I did . i am really confused now . I found the location of the tomcat server. I found the server.xml file. The port in the server.xml file was listed as 8005. I also found start.bat which I ran.

Comment: I have made an edit to the question. Please let me know

Comment: There could be multiple Tomcat installations and each one can have a different listening port. There is no reliable way to detect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The port 8005 is used as service port. [You can send a shutdown command (a configurable password)](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Security#Q2) to that port. It will not "speak" HTTP, so you cannot use your browser to connect.

The default port for delivering web-content is 8080.

But there may be other applications listen to that port. So your tomcat may not start, if the port is not available.

You asked "*How do you know, if tomcat server is installed on your PC?*". The answer to that question is: **You can't**

You can't determine, if it is installed, because it may be only extracted from a ZIP archive or packaged within another application (Like JBoss AS (I think)).

Comment: Not quite. 8005 is the default shutdown port. It only accepts a single password (configured via the shutdown attribute of the Server element) which will trigger the graceful shutdown of Tomcat. It does not understand any other commands including "stop" and "restart".

Comment: Thought the tomcat developer introduced more commands. I'll edit my post, thank you.

Comment: I agree with your point regarding the hidden tomcat with another application (Like Wildfly).

Comment: A tomcat is just a downloaded file. It is often included in other products.

Answer (score 7):

You can check in windows services if tomcat is installed it will be listed in windows services.

To check the windows service list of services installed on windows machine use

```
  WINDOWS KEY + R   and type services.msc
```

There you can find all the services related with Jasperreport server like  Tomcat and MySQL with name starting Jasperreport server Tomcat and MySQL only if these services are installed and its need to be started by selecting the option.Then you can access it through browser using this link :-

```
   http://localhost:8080
```

default port for tomcat is 8080.

Comment: Only if it runs as a service. Also you can't find embedded instances, which don't use the name tomcat at all.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make

```
     http://localhost:8080
```

work, tomcat has to be started first. You can check server.xml file in conf folder for the port information. You can search if tomcat is installed on your machine. Just go to start and then type tomcat. If it is installed it will give you the directory where it is installed. Then you can select that path and run it from command prompt. Example if tomcat is installed in C:\Programfile\tomcat. You need to set this path in command prompt,go to bin folder and startup. Example: C:\Programfile\tomcat\bin\startup. Else you can also run it by directly going to the path and run startup batch file.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to check following above steps.

Answer (score 2):

In case of Windows(in my case XP):-

1. Check the directory where tomcat is installed.
2. Open the directory called \conf in it.
3. Then search file server.xml
4. Open that file and check what is the connector port for HTTP,whre you will found something like 8009,8080 etc.
5. Suppose it found 8009,use that port as "/localhost:8009/" in your web-browser with HTTP protocol.
   Hope this will work !

Answer (score 2):

For linux ubuntu 18.04:

```
Go to terminal and command:$ sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your windows search bar, and search for the keyword `Tomcat`. If a shortcut file is found instead, you can open the source file location of the shortcut by right-clicking the shortcut file and selecting the Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Download Apache Tomcat:
https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.82/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.82.exe

Add the host address as 9494.
Add user name and password.
Add Apache tomcat server in Eclipse IDE:
In Eclipse IDE,  Windows > show views > servers. Add the tomcat version there.
Then right click and try to run it. If successfully run, check it on the browser on the specific port i.e. localhost:9494

Comment: The OP has already downloaded and installed Tomcat and started it running. You appear to be explaining how to do all that when that is **not** the question that was asked.