# Why is IIS giving me a tomcat error

Tags: tomcat, iis, iis-8.5

I have a site I'm testing locally, that I've setup bindings for. Those bindings look like

new.site.com

newa.site.com

newb.site.com

That setup works.  Now I try to add a setting like `new.blah.site.com`, and I get a 403 error, from Apache/Tomcat

> HTTP Status 403 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.28

I tried to determine if I even have Tomcat installed (this is a .NET site by the way), but couldn't find any mention of it on my drive, in services, or anywhere else.

But that's secondary to the main issue, of why adding a binding with a subvalue not working, and what am I missing?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please show me the configuration and bindings. As for Tomcat, from experience: Apache loves to hide in obscure places. What’s your setup?

Comment: What do you mean by configuration? My bindings are just those, going to http, and port 80, for all IP addresses.  The urls are mirrored in hosts, all pointing to 127.0.0.1. My setup is Windows 7 + IIS 8.5. I have literally never used Apache Tomcat in my life, so I have no idea where  it is, and only cursory knowledge of what it is.

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls You might be able to use Jexus Manager to see if any reserved URL is there for Tomcat. Meanwhile, IIS can work as reverse proxy for Tomcat. Anyway, there are multiple points Tomcat can jump in, so you are responsible for a thorough analysis.

Comment: @Kolichikov Configuration of the IIS server. What web server are you using if not Apache?

Comment: @Colton I'm using IIS.  And I mean using in the loosest sense of the word, because I just set it up through Visual Studio, and then configured the bindings. Whatever magic VS did, I'm not quite sure as to where to find it.  If you want the application pool/site settings values, I can provide that, but they don't state or seem related to apache in any way.

Comment: How have you deployed your web apps? What are their context paths? What URLs are you trying to use them?

Comment: Deployment: This is local, so they're in a folder that IIS is also pointing to (virtual directory set to the path of my app).  The urls are as mentioned in the question, but with site replaced by the company name.

Comment: @Kolichikov A big part of me wants to think you somehow have Apache installed locally on that machine. Even though you said you looked.

Comment: @Colton I would agree with you, I followed the answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302273/1193647), but I couldn't find any mention of those files, any requests on those ports, couldn't even find server.xml on my entire machine. If there's a better way to locate whether it's installed, I will gladly try that.

Comment: @Kolichikov try looking through your services for anything related to Apache and get back to me

Answer (score 0):

Run netstat -ano on a command prompt on the server and check if any other process (tomcat) is hooked to port 80.

Comment: I ran netstat, I only got 1 entry for port 80, corresponding to PID 4 -> which for me was System.